# it was not possible to establish a connection with the microsoft streaminsight server

Tags: sql, streaminsight

I have installed StreamInsight, and am able to run the Sample examples. But when I try to open the StreamInsight EVENT Flow Debugger and "Connect to Server", it shows the following error:

```
"It was not possible to establish a connection with the microsoft streaminsight server".
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method not allowed.
-------------------
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

I created the instance named "StreamInsightInstance", I used [this](http://localhost/StreamInsight/StreamInsightInstance) link to connect to server.

Can anyone please suggest the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandeep,

Which of the sample projects are you trying to run?

Check the following items:

1. Have you enabled the StreamInsight management service in the sample? Some have it enabled, some don't.
2. Make sure your user account is added to the StreamInsight Users and Performance Log Users groups.
3. Make sure you run the Event Flow Debugger as administrator.

If you have not already seen it, the documentation for debugging StreamInsight queries is located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff518532.aspx

Comment: TXPower275@ Can u plz tel me how to add User Account to StreamInsight Users and Performance Log Users groups.

Comment: In Win7, go to Start > right click on Computer > Manage > Local Users and Groups > Groups. Once you have the list of groups on your screen, you should be able to check if your account is in either one of those groups. If not, follow the prompts to add your account to each one. You may need to log off and log back in for the changes to take effect though.

Comment: Somehow now i can run with the Admin Privilege. But non-admin users are not possible to connect to Stream Insight server.